# How to Calculate the In Time and Out Time for Attendance of 3rd shift

Tags: .net

I am developing a web application for attendance controlling. I am getting data from `ZKT` Machine through `.Net` `API.` in shape of array. 
From this API I am not getting any flag for `In` or `Out Time`. So I adopt the technique that first punching time will be in `In Time`
 and the time which I am getting in last will `Out Time` in a particular date. Because I may get more then 2 punching time in a particular day.

Now I have the scenario for 3rd shift which will start 10PM and will end 6AM next day. Now I am thinking how I can get the `Out Time` in this case. The attendance date will be the date of `In Time` of a day. For example if the employee comes 05/03/2018 at 10PM the 5th of March will be the attendance date.

Please help to tackle this problem.

Data input format from machine

```
2017-06-16 09:00:00.000 I0495
2017-06-16 10:30:00.000 I0495
2017-06-16 13:00:00.000 I0495
2017-06-16 17:05:00.000 I0495

2017-06-16 09:15:00.000 I0603
2017-06-16 11:30:00.000 I0603
2017-06-16 00:00:00.000 I0603
2017-06-16 01:30:00.000 I0603
2017-06-16 17:10:00.000 I0603
```

here is code which is handling day time shift

```
while (axCZKEM1.SSR_GetGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber, out sdwEnrollNumber, out idwVerifyMode,
out idwInOutMode, out idwYear, out idwMonth, out idwDay, out idwHour, out idwMinute, out idwSecond, ref idwWorkcode))//get records from the memory
{
    if (idwYear.ToString() == DtpAtt.Value.Year.ToString() && idwMonth.ToString() == DtpAtt.Value.Month.ToString() && idwDay.ToString() == DtpAtt.Value.Day.ToString())
    {
        iGLCount++;
        lvLogs.Items.Add(iGLCount.ToString());
        lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(sdwEnrollNumber);//modify by Darcy on Nov.26 2009
        lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwVerifyMode.ToString());
        lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwInOutMode.ToString());
        lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwYear.ToString() + "-" + idwMonth.ToString() + "-" + idwDay.ToString() + " " + idwHour.ToString() + ":" + idwMinute.ToString() + ":" + idwSecond.ToString());
        lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwWorkcode.ToString());

        var id = Convert.ToInt32(mdl.GetRecord("id", "atndnce", "attendance_id='" + sdwEnrollNumber + "' and attendance_date='" + DtpAtt.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'"));
        if (id > 0)
        {
            var time = mdl.GetRecord("in_time", "atndnce", "attendance_id='" + sdwEnrollNumber + "' and attendance_date='" + idwYear.ToString() + "-" + idwMonth.ToString() + "-" + idwDay.ToString() + "'");
            mdl.UpdateRecord("atndnce", " duty_hours = '" + TxtHours.Text.ToString() + "', out_time='" + idwHour.ToString() + ":" + idwMinute.ToString() + ":" + idwSecond.ToString() + "'", "id = " + id.ToString());
        }
        else
            mdl.InsertRecord("atndnce", "attendance_id,attendance_date,in_time,posted,duty_hours,machine_id", "'" + sdwEnrollNumber + "','" + idwYear.ToString() + "-" + idwMonth.ToString() + "-" + idwDay.ToString() + "','" + idwHour.ToString() + ":" + idwMinute.ToString() + ":" + idwSecond.ToString() + "',0 ,'" + TxtHours.Text.ToString() + "','" + CmbStation.SelectedValue + "'");
        iIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us some code. Did you take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49205/algorithm-to-identify-a-shift-and-its-type-based-on-on-and-off-times ?

Comment: I did not try any for 3rd shift, however day time shift is running fine. however I have mention the input data format in question.

Comment: If you have tried it, you must have some code. Please show it. Otherwise I can't (and others maybe just won't) help you.

Comment: I have edit the question with more detail